# regex to match a pattern multiple times

Tags: python, regex

i have this following string values

```
AAA_POERAS::ZNCDAd_EROS_NOW_X_SHRIAPP_Z_DONTKNOW_J1_Z_SUITS_8907_11
BBB_POERAS::ZNCDAd_EROS_NOW_Q_SHRIAPP67_Y_DONTKNOW_J2_Y_THERE_MLA_WHICH_8906_86_25_01
```

Using regex how to extract as below, get rid of the last two digits.

```
AAA_POERAS::ZNCDAd_EROS_NOW_X_SHRIAPP_Z_DONTKNOW_J1_Z_SUITS_8907
BBB_POERAS::ZNCDAd_EROS_NOW_Q_SHRIAPP67_Y_DONTKNOW_J2_Y_THERE_MLA_WHICH_8906
```

The regex used  `(\_\d{1,2})$` only matches one patern eg. _11 or _01. i want to match _25 and _86 as well.?

Help needed.

Comment: It looks like you want to convert matches of `(?:_\d{2})+$` to empty strings.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xyB1kV/1)

Comment: Are you looking to remove the last  1 or 2 pairs of underscores?

Comment: Thank you .. it solved my problem. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` to match the pattern one or more times.

```py
re.sub(r'(\_\d{1,2})+$', '', string)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/BW6ieY)

Comment: OP only cares about double digits (he say's) `(?:_\d{2})+$`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'(?:_[0-9]{2})+$', '', input_string)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/VDcLlk/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```